# How to create a new layout for different task and call that layout inside a condition in joomla component?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

How to create a new layout for different task and call that layout inside a condition in joomla component??i have created a new component there i need to create a new default.php and want to call within a condition so pls anyone answer me how to do?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using default.php, you can create a different layout like 'your_layout.php' inside your tmpl folder of corresponding view.  You can use $this->setLayout('your_layout') in order to display this layout based on the required condition.

Hope this is what you are looking for... if not, please clarify.